# Connect to Juggernaut with Ruby

Tags: ruby, juggernaut

```
require "juggernaut"
Juggernaut.publish("channel1", "Some data")
```

The code above works if Juggernaut is on the same server as the one running the code. What's the syntax to use a Juggernaut running on another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is the same. I have a juggernaut.yml config file in my config directory with settings for each environment. To run juggernaut on port 8080 of localhost in development, I have:

```
development:
  host: 'localhost'
  port: 8080
```

To run it on a different host, you can just change that host setting (e.g. 'jugg.someserver.com')